# Is there any backport of "Grouped filters" available in Views 6.x-3.x branch?

Tags: 6, views

In Views 3 (Drupal 7), there is a nice feature when you expose a Views filter, you can select 
"Grouped filters" option and define a set of conditions.

[image: grouped filters]

Is there any module that backports this feature to Drupal 6 Views 3.x branch?

Comment: I think it is possible through https://www.drupal.org/project/views_or or https://www.drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate but I have doubt about the version of views compactability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it with [Advanced Exposed Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/aef) for views 3 version

> Advanced Exposed Forms (AEF) provides fine grained dynamic data
>   filtering by allowing the "joining" of views exposed filters into
>   groups. AEF provides AND/OR operators between individual exposed
>   filters and between groups of exposed filters. Use AEF to drill down
>   from large amounts of data to specific data sets.

[image]

Comment: thanks! This indeed answers my question. I have to wait a day to award the bounty though. Thanks again for this.